# Problema con Accordion plugin de Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

tengo una página que estoy haciendo con `Bootstrap` y `AngularJS` para el front-end y genero varios accordions en la misma página de manera dinámica con un `ng-repeat`. El problema es que cuando hago click sobre los nombres de los tabs para ampliarlos se esconde el título del tab y se muestra el contenido... es decir, no funciona como debería, y tengo otro código que está igual y si funciona... no entiendo porque ese comportamiento. Dejo el html que estoy usando y el filtro de AngularJS (Angular 1) que utilizo por las dudas...

productos.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" ng-app="tangoInfinito">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Tango Infinito - Productos</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-social.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon32x32.png">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon32x32.ico">
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Controllers/ProductosController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Services/ProductosService.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Filters/IdFilter.js"></script>

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="ProductosController">
        <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3">
                        <a id="link-logo" class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="logos/logo.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-9">
                        <h1><a href="index.html"><span id="titulo-logo-1">TANGO INFINITO</span><span id="titulo-logo-2">.com.ar</span></a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://web.facebook.com/orquestatipicalayumba" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Notitango</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Productos<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <!-- Contenido generado dinámicamente -->
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="index.html#contact-form"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contacto</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- Contenido -->
        <div id="main-content" style="padding-top: 80px; font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row row-content" ng-repeat="r in rubros">
                    <h2 class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-5 rubro" id="{{r.rubro | lowercase}}" style="font-weight: 700;">{{r.rubro | uppercase}}</h2>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 wrapper" ng-repeat="t in tipos | filter: {rubro: r.rubro}">
                        <div class="row row-content">
                            <h3 id="{{t.tipo | lowercase}}" class="tipo">{{t.tipo | uppercase}}</h3>
                            <!-- Tabs -->
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li ng-repeat="prod in productos | filter: {tipo: t.tipo}"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#{{prod.nombre | IdFilter}}">{{prod.nombre}}</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- Tabs Contenido -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="{{prod.nombre | IdFilter}}" ng-repeat="prod in productos | filter: {tipo: t.tipo}">
                                    <p style="padding-top: 10px;">{{prod.resenia}}</p>
                                    <h4>INTEGRANTES:</h4>
                                    <!-- Accordion -->
                                    <div id="{{accordionId(prod.nombre)}}" class="panel-group" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                        <div ng-repeat="integrante in prod.integrantes" class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-{{integrante.nombre | IdFilter}}">
                                                <h3 class="panel-title">
                                                   <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#{{accordionId(prod.nombre)}}" href="#{{integrante.nombre | IdFilter}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="{{integrante.nombre | IdFilter}}">{{integrante.nombre}} {{integrante.apellido}}</a>
                                                </h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-{{integrante.nombre | IdFilter}}" id="{{integrante.nombre | IdFilter}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                    <p>{{integrante.resenia}}</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!-- Fin Accordion -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="row-footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5">
                        <h5 style="font-weight: bolder;">Contacto</h5>
                        <address>
                          <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>: +54 9 343-5064897<br>
                          <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>: <a href="mailto:infotangoinfinito@gmail.com">infotangoinfinito@gmail.com</a>
                       </address>
                    </div>
                    <div id="social-icons" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-4">
                        <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding: 10px 10px;">
                            <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebbok" href="http://www.facebook.com/orquestatipicalayumba/?ref=bookmarks" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/PetruccelliFac2" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDz466X5LlESY5SJ_tlLmjA" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:infotangoinfinito@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bolder;">&copy; Copyright 2016 Tango Infinito</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="js/send-email.js"></script>
        <script src="js/appear-navbar-productos.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                //Tomo el nodo al que luego le agrego li según correspondan
                //<li class="dropdown-header">Rubro</li> Para los rubros
                //<li><a href="#tipo">Tipo</a></li> 
                var lista = $("ul.dropdown-menu");

                var navbarProductosLista = undefined;

                //Chequea hasta que la variable navbarList de ProductosController esta asignada
                function checkVariable() {
                    //Toma la variable navbarList del scope de ProductosController
                    //para agregar la lista de manera dinámica
                    navbarProductosLista = angular.element($("[ng-controller=ProductosController]")).scope().navbarList;

                    if(navbarProductosLista != undefined) {
                        for(var i = 0; i < navbarProductosLista.length; i++) {
                            if(navbarProductosLista[i].isHeader === true) {
                                var nodo = $("<li><a href='productos.html#" + navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion.toLowerCase() + "'>" +  navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion + "</a></li>");
                                nodo.children().addClass("dropdown-header");
                                lista.append(nodo);
                            }
                            else {
                                var nodo = $("<li><a href='productos.html#" + navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion.toLowerCase() + "'>" +  navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion + "</a></li>");
                                lista.append(nodo);
                            }
                        }

                        clearInterval(id);
                    }

                    $("ul li:first-child")
                    .addClass("active");

                    $(".tab-content div:first-child")
                    .addClass("in active");
                };

                var id = setInterval(checkVariable, 250);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

ProductosController.js:

```
(function(){

    var module = angular.module("tangoInfinito");

    var ProductosController = function($scope, ProductosService) {

        function idAsignado(lista, producto) {
            var listaLength = lista.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < listaLength; i++) {
                if (lista[i].producto === producto) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        };

        var listaIdAccordions = [];
        var accordionNumber = 1;
        $scope.accordionId = function(prodNombre) {
            if(!idAsignado(listaIdAccordions, prodNombre)) {
                var accId = "accordion" + accordionNumber;
                accordionNumber++;
                listaIdAccordions.push({
                    producto: prodNombre,
                    id: accId
                });
                //console.log(listaIdAccordions);
                //console.log("Nuevo id asignado");
                return accId;
            }
            else {
                var largo = listaIdAccordions.length;
                for(var i = 0; i < largo; i++) {
                    if(listaIdAccordions[i].producto === prodNombre) {
                        //console.log(listaIdAccordions);
                        //console.log("Id devuelto");
                        return listaIdAccordions[i].id;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var armarLista = function($rubros, $tipos) {
            var lista = [];
            var rubrosTemp = $rubros.slice(0);
            var tiposTemp = $tipos.slice(0);

            for(var i = 0; i < rubrosTemp.length; i++) {

                var rubro = rubrosTemp[i].rubro.toUpperCase();

                lista.push( {descripcion: rubro, isHeader: true} ); 
                for(var j = 0; j < tiposTemp.length; j++) {
                    if(tiposTemp[j].rubro === rubrosTemp[i].rubro) {
                        lista.push( {descripcion: tiposTemp[j].tipo, isHeader: false} );
                    }
                }
            }

            return lista;
        };

        var getDatosFromService = function() {
            ProductosService.getDatos().success(function(response) {

                //Lista para armar el menu desplegable (menu productos) de la barra de navegación
                //Esta lista es tomada por index.html y productos.html 
                //(en un script al final de la página) para armar el menu dinamicamente
                $scope.navbarList = armarLista(response["rubros"], response["tipos"]);
                $scope.productos = response["productos"];
                $scope.rubros = response["rubros"];
                $scope.tipos = response["tipos"];
            });
        }

        getDatosFromService();
    };

    module.controller("ProductosController", ProductosController);

})();
```

IdFilter.js:

```
(function() {

    var module = angular.module("tangoInfinito");

    var IdFilter = function() {
        return function(item) {
            var id = "";
            id = item.toLowerCase();
            id = id.replace(/\s/g, "-");
            return id;
        };
    };

    module.filter("IdFilter", IdFilter);

})();
```

Y el comportamiento del que les hablo:
[image: bien]
[image: mal]

EDITO: estuve viendo que por alguna razón cuando hago click sobre algun titulo, al div que tiene la clase `panel-heading` se le agrega la clase `collapse`, pero no la `in`, por lo que la propiedad `display` pasa a ser `none`, y también se le agrega un `style="height: 20px;"`, que asumo deberá ser a través de `JavaScript`, ya que al principio el elemento no lo tiene. Pero no puedo deducir desde donde vienen estos cambios...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, encontré el porqué del error... La razón es un script que hice al final de la página para hacer la dropdown-list de la barra de navegación y para ponerle las clases `active in` a los primeros tabs de cada rubro pero resulta que también le agrega las clases `active in` a los div con la clase `panel-heading` haciendo que el plugin se comporte de forma errónea. La solución fue sacarle las clases `active-in` a los div con la clase `panel-heading` con el método `removeClass` de `jQuery`. Dejo la solución:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Tomo el nodo al que luego le agrego li según correspondan
            //<li class="dropdown-header">Rubro</li> Para los rubros
            //<li><a href="#tipo">Tipo</a></li> 
            var lista = $("ul.dropdown-menu");

            var navbarProductosLista = undefined;

            //Chequea hasta que la variable navbarList de ProductosController esta asignada
            function checkVariable() {
                //Toma la variable navbarList del scope de ProductosController
                //para agregar la lista de manera dinámica
                navbarProductosLista = angular.element($("[ng-controller=ProductosController]")).scope().navbarList;

                if(navbarProductosLista != undefined) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < navbarProductosLista.length; i++) {
                        if(navbarProductosLista[i].isHeader === true) {
                            var nodo = $("<li><a href='productos.html#" + navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion.toLowerCase() + "'>" +  navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion + "</a></li>");
                            nodo.children().addClass("dropdown-header");
                            lista.append(nodo);
                        }
                        else {
                            var nodo = $("<li><a href='productos.html#" + navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion.toLowerCase() + "'>" +  navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion + "</a></li>");
                            lista.append(nodo);
                        }
                    }
                    clearInterval(id);
                }

                $("ul li:first-child")
                .addClass("active");

                //Esta es la linea que causa el error
                $(".tab-content div:first-child")
                .addClass("in active");

                //Y esta es la linea que lo soluciona
                $(".panel-heading")
                .removeClass("in active");
            };

            var id = setInterval(checkVariable, 250);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer que un div (en este caso un tab) tenga contenido unico oculto deben tener algo en comun. A lo que me refiero es que si un `producto` tiene `integrantes` estos `integrantes` tienen que tener algo en comun con ese producto.

Cree el siguiente ejemplo :

```
$scope.productos = [
{ 
    nombre: "Producto 1", 
    id: 1, 
    integrantes: [
        { nombre: "Integrante 1", edad: 17, correo: "ejemplo@ejemplo.cl" }, 
        { nombre: "Integrante 2", edad: 40, correo: "ejemplo@ejemplo.cl" }, 
        { nombre: "Integrante 3", edad: 22, correo: "ejemplo@ejemplo.cl" }
    ] 
},
{   nombre: "Producto 2", 
    id: 2, 
    integrantes: [
        { nombre: "Integrante 4", edad: 20, correo: "ejemplo@ejemplo.cl" }, 
        { nombre: "Integrante 5", edad: 35, correo: "ejemplo@ejemplo.cl" }, 
        { nombre: "Integrante 6", edad: 60, correo: "ejemplo@ejemplo.cl" }
    ] 
},
{   nombre: "Producto 3", 
    id: 3, 
    integrantes: [
        { nombre: "Integrante 7", edad: 80, correo: "ejemplo@ejemplo.cl" }, 
        { nombre: "Integrante 8", edad: 18, correo: "ejemplo@ejemplo.cl" }, 
        { nombre: "Integrante 9", edad: 45, correo: "ejemplo@ejemplo.cl" }
    ] 
}];
```

Como puedes ver, cada producto tiene su arreglo de integrantes.

Tambien cree una función llamada `$scope.mostrarHijos` y una `$scope.isHijoShow`

```
$scope.mostrarHijos = function(integrante) {
    if ($scope.isHijosShow(integrante)) {
        $scope.shownHijos = null;
    } else {
        $scope.shownHijos = integrante;
    }
};
$scope.isHijosShow = function(integrante) {
    return $scope.shownHijos === integrante;
};
```

En la parte visual simplemente :

```
<div ng-repeat="producto in productos">
   <h2>{{producto.nombre}}</h2>
   <div ng-repeat="integrante in producto.integrantes" ng-click="mostrarHijos(integrante)">
       <p>{{integrante.nombre}}</p>
       <div ng-show="isHijosShow(integrante)" style="margin-left:40px;">
         <p> Edad : {{integrante.edad}}</p>
         <p> Correo : {{integrante.correo}}</p>
       </div>
   </div>  
</div>
```

Te dejo un codepen de este codigo funcionando [codepen](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/JbBYgx)

Comment: Perdón por la ignorancia pero, me podrías explicar un poco el código? Porque haces lo que haces? No logro entenderlo del todo como funciona... De todas formas mi pregunta era porque no funcionan correctamente los accordeons de bootstrap que estoy poniendo en la página... no logro ver la relación de tu respuesta con la pregunta... pero gracias igualmente por tomarte el tiempo para responder

Comment: Boostrap te entrega el diseño perfecto, pero si implementas angularjs puedes ocupar los tags que este proporciona. Aqui hay por asi llamarlos "grupos" que serian tus productos. Cada uno de ellos tiene un subgrupo que son los integrantes. Mi codigo sencillamente pregunta si hay algun subgrupo visible, si hay lo oculta y muestra el que el usuario dio click para expandir. Que parte del codigo no entiendes? Entiendo que tu pregunta es porque el acordeon bootstrap no funciona, yo te di una solucion con angularjs ya que lo tienes implementado pero no lo usas.

Comment: Lo voy a probar... pero de todas formas me gustaría entender porque no me funciona el plugin, cuando, supuestamente, debería funcionar... quiero saber que es lo que estoy haciendo mal... después veré si lo implemento con `Bootstrap` o con `AngularJS` pero quiero entender porque no me funcionan las cosas... muchas gracias igual por el tiempo

Comment: Apenas tenga un computador a mano voy a probar tu codigo y buscare el error, pero como estabas implementando angularjs te di esta respuesta , espero que puedas solucionar tu problema antes, saludos!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @sioesi, te lo agradeceria muchismo

Comment: sioesi me puse a ver bien el ejemplo que me dejaste y no se si me sirve para el problema que tengo, porque lo que quiero es hacer un accordion con los integrante de los productos, no un accordion por cada producto. Es decir, un accordion por producto, que tenga los integrantes de ese producto y muestre la informacion de cada uno. @sioesi

Comment: Pero como? Cual es la diferencia entre "no un acordion por cada producto" con "un acordion por producto"? Si quieres mostrar la informacion de los integrantes basta con mostrarla... no entiendo

Comment: Puedes dejar un ejemplo mas claro de lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: Si, perdón la confusión... En los productos tengo un array de integrantes no? Lo que yo quiero hacer es un accordion por cada array de integrantes que se corresponda con cada producto, y que lo que muestren los items del accordion sea la información de los integrantes (porque los integrantes tienen nombre, apellido y una pequeña reseña). Para ponerte un ejemplo supongamos que tengo 2 productos. El primero con 3 integrantes y el segundo con 2. El accordion1 debería ser de 3 items y el accordion2 de 2 items. No se si me explico bien. No me explayo mas porque no me lo permite el comentario.

Comment: Como muestro en la foto de arriba, los productos se muestran en un tab, y lo que quiero lograr es que los integrantes de ese producto en particular se muestren en un accordeon, pudiendo elegir ver la información de un integrante en particular haciendo click en su nombre. Si quisiera ver otro producto sencillamente hago click en otro tab. Avisame si no se entiende que modifico la pregunta y subo una foto con lo que te estoy comentando a ver si se entiende mejor. @sioesi

Comment: Perfecto, en unos momentos mas edito!

Comment: @AugustoHerbel entonces, quieres que los tabs (productos) tenga los acordions con nombre de los integrantes y cuando pincho el nombre, me muestre la info del integrante?

Comment: @AugustoHerbel actualice mi respuesta y el codepen

Comment: esto es lo que queria @sioesi... me faltaría la parte de estilo nada más pero el comportamiento es esto... mil gracias por el tiempo y la dedicación!

Comment: de nada!! un saludo y exito!